# SimpleDateFormat bug

Tags: java, android

```
 /**
 * Validates a date in String data type according to the given date format.
 * 
 * @param validDateFormat
 *           valid date format e.g. YYYY/MM/DD
 * @param strDate
 *            - the date to be validated
 * @return true if the date is valid according to the given format
 */
public static boolean isValidDate(final String strDate, final String validDateFormat) {
    boolean result = true;

    try {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(validDateFormat) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(strDate)
                && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(strDate)) {
            dateValidator = new SimpleDateFormat(validDateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
            dateValidator.setLenient(false);
            dateValidator.parse(strDate);


            Log.i(TAG, "***Date entered: "+ strDate +
                    "\nDate parsed back: "+dateValidator.format(dateValidator.parse(strDate)));

            dateValidator = null;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        result = false;
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        result = false;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I input for example:

```
boolean result = isValidDate("21/May/201l", "dd/MMM/yyyy");
//result = true
```

be reminded that the input is not two-thousand-eleven, its two-hundred and one + a letter 'l'.

logs:

```
  ***Date entered: 21/May/201l
   Date parsed back: 21/May/0201
```

it doesn't throw any exception, and doesn't make it false!!!!

WHYYYYYYYYYY!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: One idea would be to impose a rather severe restriction on your inputs: the input *date* string and *format* string must match *exactly*; you could enforce this by doing something like:

```
Date parsed = dateValidator.parse(strDate);
return strDate.equals(dateValidator.format(parsed));
```

In other words, verify that formatting the actual `Date` object returns a string that is identical to whatever was passed in. This ensures that you won't have erroneous *positive* results when there are actually invalid characters in the format string (since these will be ignored for the purposes of re-formatting the date).

I'm not sure it's a good solution in general, as it may be overly restrictive. I haven't really thought it through very carefully. But anyway, it's an idea.

---

From [the documentation of `DateFormat.parse`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) (which is inherited by `SimpleDateFormat`):

> The method may not use the entire text
>   of the given string.

Also, from the "Throws" section of the same method:

> ParseException - if **the beginning of
>   the specified string** cannot be parsed.

Notice this: if I instantiate a `SimpleDateFormat` with the string "yyyy-MM-dd", then it will successfully parse the string "2011-05-12abcdefg":

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(format.parse("2011-05-12abcdefg"));
```

The above outputs (on my machine):

```
Thu May 12 00:00:00 CDT 2011
```

So basically it's just parsing *as much as it can*.

The fact that this is the behavior, even with `setLenient(false)`, is indeed a bit strange to me.

Comment: So how to make a work around for my problem, any clues?, ***king 'L', haha

Comment: well, ive been working around by using reg-ex to handle this problem, it seem that its a language bug, since it accepts 'l' when preceded by numbers. java bug

Comment: well by using Reg-ex parsing, i finally got it working see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986392/how-to-match-this-date-format-with-a-regex

Comment: @Mark: But in that question, you're requiring a *specific* format! I thought your `isValidDate` function is supposed to accept the desired format as a *parameter* (`validDateFormat`, yes?). This strikes me as a much more difficult problem.

Comment: oh yeah well, that's true. but just to solve the issue. But if you have any good suggestion. I can have them as well. tnx :))

Comment: using parseposition would make sure that the parse is a complete parse

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create your own validator here.  It will give back valid dates for trailing f and l due to how it casts numbers.

I suggest using the various iterations of String.indexOf to find the index positions of the "/" and then test the substrings.  It should be pretty readily apparent as to how to validate the number portions of the date, at least.  Your usage of Jan Feb Mar etc may complicate the middle validation  ;)

Edited to your comment:

Something like - i cant see your question in edit mode, so bear with me here,

```
String day, month, year;
int div1, div2;
div1=yourDateString.indexOf("/");
div2=yourDateString.indexOf("/",div1);
day =yourDateString.substring(0,div1-1);
month =yourDateString.substring(div1+1,div2-1);
year =yourDateString.substring(div2+1,yourDateString.length()-1);
```

(I'm posting from my phone so I dont have full editor context and punctuation is a pain in the ass, so I hope you get the idea.  this leaves you with individual strings of each field to test.)

Comment: ok, how to regex this format, 09/May/2011, with 2011 donot contains any letteR?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to do this is to use ParsePosition when parsing.

```
 `                        String d = "10/31/201lll";
                    ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
                    sdf.setLenient(false);

                    try {
                            System.out.println(sdf.parse(d, pp));
                            System.out.println(pp.getIndex());
                            System.out.println(d.length());
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

`

The parsePosition.getIndex() gives you the index of the character after the last character that was used for parsing. Comparing this to the length of your input string should tell you if this was an absolute parse or a partial parse.

Answer (score -1):

The reason that that is happening, I believe, is because a ### + the letter l at the end *is* a valid number in Java. The 'l' indicates that the value is a long integer. So, the year you are posting is really May 21, 201, and Java handles the letter. (Try switching it to an m or something and it should break.)

Comment: but im trying to check if the user input is valid, and 201l is not VALID. :((

Comment: @MarkJ - I agree that it is not valid from a human standpoint. It is valid from the language standpoint. What you need to do to solve this particular problem is have an extra check in your parser that there are no letters within your numeric values (both the dd and the yyyy). Add that extra check and it should solve your problem.

Comment: aw, i should make my own parser then? :((

Comment: OscarRyz, it should be a letter 'l'

Comment: @MarkJ I was answering @JasCav suggestion to use another char.

Comment: hehe, but it is my question that you should answer, hehe :))

Comment: I don't think this is actually the correct explanation. If the reason it works is that "L" is interpreted by the parser as signifying a `long`, then other letters such as "a", "b", "c", etc. should not work. But they all do, according to my (limited) tests.

Comment: can I override the parsing function of simpledateformat? hha, i need a better implementation to handle the LLLLLL