# How to match this date format with a regex?

Tags: java, regex

hi to all regex master out there, I know you have a work around with regards to my problem. hehe

```
02-May-2011
```

or

```
22-May-2011
```

or

```
2-May-2011
```

(dd-MMM-yyyy)
with yyyy not accepting any other characters than digit

Comment: Please don't ask a question in one format, wait for answers and then change the format of the question.  If you need to do that, please clearly mark as an edit in your question text.

Comment: i dont know how to mark this question as edited, hehe:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[0-9]{1,2}/[a-zA-Z]{3}/[0-9]{4}
```

That's assuming that the month is a 3-letter version: eg, Jan, Feb, Mar.

Updated version to match the changes to the question:

```
[0-9]{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```

As has been mentioned, this won't actually validate the date, it'll just validate that the string matches the format of: *1 or 2 numbers, a dash, 3 letters, a dash, 4 numbers*.

Comment: someone can enter XYZ as month, it won't handle that.

Comment: alex's answer looks correct. You can experiment with the various options using [nregex](http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx) or [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

Comment: @retrodrone: I'd post the links to nregex and Regex Hero as a comment on the question as they're not pertinent to any specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Town-sensei.

Comment: For months full names : [0-9]{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3,9}-[0-9]{4}

Answer (score 4):

```
^\d{1,2}/[a-zA-Z]+/\d{4}$
```

Is probably what you're looking for. Although the technically correct one is:

```
/^([12]\d|3[01])/(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(t(ember)?)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)/\d{4}$/i
```

Sorry for not validating February and the number of days in a month, but there are some things just not worth doing in regular expressions ;)

Comment: +1 for suggesting that _that_ level of date validation is maybe better handled by something else ;)

Comment: Looks like the OP changed the date format on all of us! To fix, change the `/`s (apart from leading & trailing in the second example, those are delimiters) to `\-`.

Comment: @minitech: Yep, -1 all round ;) You shouldn't need to escape the dash, just `-` should be enough.

Comment: @minitech: I was just referring to the fact that all our answers are incorrect and therefore 'not useful' after the question was changed :)

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat instead of using regexp. Read the tutorial at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html for more info.

Comment: SIMPLEDATEFORMAT HAS A BUG!!, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985912/simpledateformat-bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /**
     * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
     * User: S34N
     * Date: 2013/07/30
     * Time: 8:21 AM
     * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
     */



    //Import the required classes/packages
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    public class dateInputScan {

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            dateInputScan run = new dateInputScan();
            run.dateInputScan();
        }

        public void dateInputScan() {

            //Instantiating variables
            String lvarStrDateOfTransaction = null;
            DateFormat formatter = null;
            Date lvarObjDateOfTransaction = null;

            //Use one of the following date formats.
            lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "29/07/2013";
            //lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "29-07-2013";
            //lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "20130729";
            //lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "2013-07-29";
            //lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "29/07/2013";

            //You can also add your own regex (Regular Expression)
            if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})")) {
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            } else if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})")) {
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            } else if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})")) {
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            } else if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})")) {
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            } else if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})")) {
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            }

            try {
                lvarObjDateOfTransaction = formatter.parse(lvarStrDateOfTransaction);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Date: " + lvarObjDateOfTransaction);

            } catch (Exception ex) {    //Catch the Exception in case the format is not found.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here are almost all possible regex variations of the Date pattern:

```
private final static Pattern DATE_PATTERN_1 = 

        Pattern.compile (
            "(?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat) " + 
            "(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|June?|July?|Aug|Sept?|Oct|Nov|Dec) " + 
            "\\d\\d \\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d \\S+ \\d\\d\\d\\d", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

private final static Pattern DATE_PATTERN_2 = 
        Pattern.compile (
            "\\d{4}.\\d{2}.\\d{2}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

private final static Pattern DATE_PATTERN_3 = 
        Pattern.compile (
            "\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

private final static Pattern DATE_PATTERN_4 = 
        Pattern.compile (
            "([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);        

private final static Pattern DATE_PATTERN_5 = 
        Pattern.compile (
            "^([12]\\d|3[01]).(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(t(ember)?)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?).\\d{4})$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Please note that "." character stand for any char.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is date, which you are trying to find a match, using SimpleDateFormat instead of a regex based match check should be the appropriate solution. Hopefully, the below snippet should do the job.

```
public static boolean dateFormatValidate(String strDate,String dateFormat)
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    String strParsed = null;
    Date parsed =null;

    try
    {
        parsed = formatter.parse(strDate);
        strParsed = formatter.format(parsed);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        MYLogger.logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }

    return strDate.equals(strParsed);
}
```